# assigning nested json to a variable

Tags: json, angular, typescript, mean-stack

I have the following interface:

```js
export interface IdataTypes {
dataType: {
  Categories: string[],
  isSelected: boolean,
}
}
```

and the following JSON

```js
{
  "Sensitive Personal Data": {
    "isSelected": "false",
    "legalReference": "",
    "Categories": [
      "Health Data",
      "Genetic Data",
      "Biometric Data",
      "Trade Union Data",
      "Religious Data",
      "Political Opinion",
      "Philosophical Belief",
      "Racial or Ethic Origin",
      "Sex Life",
      "Sexual Orientation"
    ]
  },
"Personal Data with Higher Risk":{
  "isSelected":"false",
  "legalReference":"",
  "Categories":["location","Financial/Social Status","Data Related to Profiling",
    "video surveillance","data on adoption and custody"]
}


}
```

i want to read and assigne the *"dataTypeCategories"* of the file to a variable of the Interface file. so i do the following

```js
 for(let i=0; i<response["Personal Data with Higher Risk"].Categories.length;i++){
        this.dataTypeHighRisk["Personal Data with Higher Risk"][i].Categories.push
        (response["Personal Data with Higher Risk"].Categories[i]);
        this.dataTypeHighRisk["Personal Data with Higher Risk"][i].isSelected=false;
       ;
      }
```

and i receive this error: core.js:1542 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: Categories is not defined

could you advice me on how to this? I am new to both javascript and angular.

**update** the array is defined as:  dataTypeHighRisk: IdataTypes[]=[];
i do not know how to define the properti "personal data with high risk/

Comment: That field is a child of `dataTypeCategories`, so you need `response.dataTypeCategories["Personal Data with Higher Risk"].Categories` instead

Comment: sorry i have posted wrong JSON file. have updated it

Comment: Okay, and can you see which line is throwing the error? Where is `this.dataTypeHighRisk["Personal Data with Higher Risk"]` being defined?

Comment: yess, here: this.dataTypeHighRisk[i]["Personal Data with Higher Risk"].Categories.push

Comment: Where is `this.dataTypeHighRisk` and `this.dataTypeHighRisk["Personal Data with Higher Risk"]` being defined?

Comment: "this.dataTypeHighRisk" is defined as follows: dataTypeHighRisk: IdataType[]=[]

Comment: If `dataTypeHighRisk` is an array, then `this.dataTypeHighRisk["Personal Data with Higher Risk"]` is probably going to be undefined. Where are you then defining it?

Comment: no where! i dont know how to define it!

Comment: Firstly, I would suggest making `this.dataTypeHighRisk` an Object instead of an array. Secondly, check if the value is undefined (`if(this.dataTypeHighRisk["Personal Data with Higher Risk"] == null)`) and if so, set it to whatever you want.

Comment: the same error. why not array? since it may hold several categories

Comment: So can an object. An array holds things by index, but you want to look it up by name, i.e. `Personal Data with Higher Risk`. Can you update the code to show where you're now initialising the `dataTypeHighRisk` and `dataTypeHighRisk["Personal Data with Higher Risk"] ` properties?

Comment: i did update the question

Comment: If you're still having trouble, can you please put the latest version of all of the code in a single code snippet?  The current format is hard to follow.